# XSB error#126 load pcre dlls

Tags: prolog, xsb

I’m using Win64 XSB in Eclipse with Pro-DT.

I’m getting an error loading the native lib when trying to use pcre:
(On first use it also compiled without error.)

```
[pcretest loaded]
[pcre loaded]
[pcreconfig loaded]

+Warning[XSB]: [Runtime/C] Cannot load library pcre4pl.dll or C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\packages\pcre\cc\pcre4pl.dll; error #126
++Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Miscellaneous] Error in loading file C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\packages\pcre\cc\pcre4pl.xwam
```

I checked, and the DLL in question is in the current config directory alongside of XSB.exe. Anything I need to change?
Sorry if this is a common/RTFM issue – just getting used to things.

It looks like StackOverflow doesn’t have much activity for XSB – any other resources, or is the mailing list the preferred forum?

thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include what steps you exactly did to reach that error.

Comment: If you want to reach the core XSB developers, use the XSB developers mailing list.

Comment: false: Simply trying to run the pcretest that comes with the /examples is sufficient for me to repro.
paulo: yes, thanks - I just thought I'd try a public forum first